# Combining rows with similar items in Pandas Dataframe- Need the fastest method

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set with entry or exit times. There is a column for entry_exit. It will have a value of -1 for entry and 1 for exit.

```
dict = {
    'name': {0: 'john', 1: 'jacob', 2: 'john', 3: 'Tom', 4: 'Tom', 5: 'john', 6: 'jacob', 7: 'Tom', 8: 'jacob', 9: 'Tom', 10: 'jacob', 11: 'john'},
    'entry_exit': {0: -1, 1: -1, 2: 1, 3: -1, 4: 1, 5: -1, 6: 1, 7: -1, 8: -1, 9: 1, 10: 1, 11: 1},
    'building': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'B', 5: 'A', 6: 'A', 7: 'A', 8: 'A', 9: 'A', 10: 'A', 11: 'A'}, 
    'instance': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 2, 9: 1, 10: 2, 11: 2}, 
    'time': {0: 0, 1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 6, 4: 7, 5: 8, 6: 10, 7: 12, 8: 13, 9: 14, 10: 14, 11: 15}
}
```

[image: df]

I need to find similar rows with the same name, building and instance and find the time_spend.
time_spend = exit_time - entry_time.
Currently I am doing

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
df.time = df.time * df.entry_exit
new = df.groupby(['building','name','instance'])['time'].apply(sum).reset_index()
```

to get,

[image]

but, my data set is really huge (millions of rows). And it doesn't seem very fast. It can process approximately 5000 rows/second. Is there any way that I could speed it up?

Or is there any way that I could combine the entry-exit pair of one instance for the whole df, efficiently?

[image]

Comment: You could try replacing `.apply(sum)` with simply `.sum()`.

Comment: @thesilkworm Thank you for the response. I have tried ```.sum()``` as you said. It is very fast (approximately 50x), but the resulting values are not accurate. With ```.apply(sum)``` the result is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Two methods you can try which will speed up your code:

#### 1:

Use `sum(axis=1)` instead of `apply(sum)`:

```
df.time = df.time * df.entry_exit
new = df.groupby(['building','name','instance'])['time'].sum(axis=1).reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
  building   name  instance  time
0        A    Tom         1     2
1        A  jacob         1     7
2        A  jacob         2     1
3        A   john         1     5
4        A   john         2     7
5        B    Tom         1     1
```

---

#### 2:

Use `GroupBy.diff` & `dropna`:

```
df['time_spend'] = df.groupby(['name', 'building', 'instance'])['time'].diff()

df.dropna(subset=['time_spend']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
    name  entry_exit building  instance  time  time_spend
0   john           1        A         1     5         5.0
1    Tom           1        B         1     7         1.0
2  jacob           1        A         1    10         7.0
3    Tom           1        A         1    14         2.0
4  jacob           1        A         2    14         1.0
5   john           1        A         2    15         7.0
```